# Errors were found while processing: linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic

Tags: package-management, upgrade

Yesterday, I was updating my computer, but suddenly my internet connection failed. When I restarted it and tried to continue with the process, I had this message:

```
gonzalocriollog@gonzalocriollog-Inspiron-5420:~$ sudo apt-get upgrade
[sudo] password for gonzalocriollog:               
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
Calculating upgrade... Done
The following packages were automatically installed and are no longer required:
  amd64-microcode thermald
Use 'sudo apt autoremove' to remove them.
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8.141 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 437137 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (4.15.0-36.39~16.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Now I can't download anything, neither update my current apps.

After `sudo apt-get autoremove`, I get:

```
gonzalocriollog@gonzalocriollog-Inspiron-5420:~$ sudo apt-get autoremove
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  amd64-microcode linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic thermald
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 3 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
1 not fully installed or removed.
After this operation, 8.803 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] y
(Reading database ... 437137 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (4.15.0-36.39~16.04.1) ...
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/initramfs-tools:
update-initramfs: Deleting /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-36-generic
/etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub:
/usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig: 11: /etc/default/grub: splash: not found
run-parts: /etc/kernel/postrm.d/zz-update-grub exited with return code 127
dpkg: error processing package linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic (--remove):
 subprocess installed post-removal script returned error exit status 1
Removing amd64-microcode (3.20180524.1~ubuntu0.16.04.2) ...
update-initramfs: deferring update (trigger activated)
Removing thermald (1.5-2ubuntu4) ...
Processing triggers for initramfs-tools (0.122ubuntu8.13) ...
update-initramfs: Generating /boot/initrd.img-4.15.0-34-generic
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/kbl_guc_ver9_14.bin for module i915
W: Possible missing firmware /lib/firmware/i915/bxt_guc_ver8_7.bin for module i915
Processing triggers for dbus (1.10.6-1ubuntu3.3) ...
Processing triggers for man-db (2.7.5-1) ...
Errors were encountered while processing:
 linux-image-4.15.0-36-generic
E: Sub-process /usr/bin/dpkg returned an error code (1)
```

Comment: Looks like your /usr/sbin/grub-mkconfig file became corrupted...though I cannot imagine why that might happen coincidentally with a networking hiccup. That file is provided by the `grub-common` package. Consider reinstalling that package. With two suspicious events, look up how to run a SMART test on your storage hardware.

Comment: @user535733, It worked! I uninstalled `grub-common`. Then, I had  `sudo apt-get clean
E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`. To solve this, I used `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`. Finally, `sudo apt-get update`.
Thank you very much!

Answer (score 2):

guys!

Thanks to [@user535733](https://askubuntu.com/users/19626/user535733) for the solution!

First, I uninstalled `grub-common`.

After, I got this message:

`sudo apt-get clean E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable) E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/`.

To solve this, I used `sudo rm /var/lib/apt/lists/* -vf`.

Finally, `sudo apt-get update`. 
Now I can install and update apps again.

Thank you very much!